# Changing KDE user avatar

Tags: arch-linux, kde

I'm trying to change my user avatar but I can't find the [Password & User Account](http://www.kubuntu.org/docs/kquickguide/C/ch03s07.html#user-passworduseraccount).

In my *System Settings → Common Appearance and Behavior → Account Details* there are only 2 elements, Paths and Social Desktop.

What package do I need to install? I've installed KDE-Base only on my Arch Linux.

Comment: My Kubuntu shows I have `kuser` and `manage-users` installed (and, of course, much more - but those look to me like they could be a match). Not sure how those packages are called in arch though...

Comment: I've installed kdeadmin-kuser but the section is still missing :( Can't find manage-user...I'll google for it

Comment: Found it! [kdepasswd](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=kdepasswd&maintainer=&flagged=)

Comment: You might want to answer your own question, for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing package was [kdepasswd](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=kdepasswd&maintainer=&flagged=)

Comment: `kdepasswd` in KDE 5 only changes the password and does not let you change the avatar.

Answer (score 9):

In KDE 5 (Plasma), the user avatar is stored in the user's home directory:

```
~/.face.icon
```

If you are using SDDM as your login-manager, you can also store icons in:

```
/usr/share/sddm/faces
```

Comment: What file-format should `.face.icon` have? From the extension I would guess it should be a `.ico` (`application/x-icon`) file? But that seems venerable and unlikely.

Comment: @exhuma I do not know all possible supported formats, but mine is: `$ file ~/.face.icon`
`~/.face.icon: PNG image data, 533 x 400, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced`

Answer (score 1):

To change the avatar of the User Switcher plasmoid copy a 256x256, PNG file to ~/.face.icon
[UserSwitch.plasmoid Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XfV4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated answer for 2023.

There should be a "Personalisation > Users" page in KDE's settings application `systemsettings`, where you should be able to click on the user's avatar to change it. The binary `systemsettings` is owned by the package `systemsettings`, but the files for the "Users" page is owned by the package `plasma-workspace`, which is a dependency of `systemsettings`. So if you don't find this page, something is seriously wrong with your installation.

As of the user avatar, I'm not sure why everyone's saying `~/.face.icon`. AFAIK that is very much a legacy location, and has the big problem of not showing up in your login manager (default for KDE is SDDM). In other words, you won't be able to see your custom avatar until you are logged in.

Right now, if you set your user avatar using `systemsettings`, the image gets stored in `/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/<your-user-name>`, which is picked up by both SDDM and KDE. See [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE#Faces).

Answer (score 1):

With the latest versions of KDE-Plasma, you can choose a graphic PNG in the user panel. I made mine 256 pixels squared, but I'm not sure that is still required.